# flex item set height cannot show specific height

Tags: html, css

following is my code, I set `.it {height: 100px}` but in my chrome, "it" show height 60px

```css
.c {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.it {
  min-height: 0;
  background-color: #212121;
  height: 100px;
}

.it2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: pink;
}

.it2>div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="it">
  </div>
  <div class="it2">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to that item

Comment: because you overflow the flex-parent and as such a `flex-shrink: 1` occure. A `flex-shrink` happens by default when a negative available sapce is elft (overflow of the parent`